# CKEditor: Add loading gif to dialog before iframe loads

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor, loading

I'm using CKEditor with my custom iframe dialog.

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe(
   'myCustomPluginIframe',
   'Add New Command',
   '/Test/AddNewCommand', 360, 110,.......
```

The problem is that when I'm opening dialog it's taking some time before it loads iframe in it. How can I show some loading gif image before that or maybe load iframe before clicking on the button(load iframe with CKEditor)?

Answer (score 0):

Use dialog event `show` ([here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-event-show)) to add your custom preloader HTML code and iframe event `onContentLoad` ([here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-static-method-addIframe)) to hide or remove it.